# Borrar una tabla al cambiar los datos de un input

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json

Tengo la siguiente tabla:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la cual se genera inmediatamente, pero al realizar un cambio de fechas con

```
 $("#p-fechaIni").change(function() {

          tablaP($("#p-fechaIni").val(), $("#p-fechaFin").val());

        });
```

manda los datos y hace un nuevo JSON con nuevos datos y me crea otra tabla pero debajo de la misma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La pregunta aquí es como puedo eliminar la tabla que esta creada al hacer el cambio de fechas y me crea la nueva tabla con los nuevos datos, que no la ponga debajo de la otra tabla, si no que sea solo una. 
intente hacerlo con la función `remove()`:

```
$("#p-fechaIni").change(function() {
   $("#tablaDatos").remove();
   tablaP($("#p-fechaIni").val(), $("#p-fechaFin").val());

});
```

> HTML

```
<table id="tablaDatos" class="table table-striper table-bordered table-hover">
</table> 


function tablaP(datoFechaI, datoFechaF){
        peticionDatos(
          '<?= base_url(); ?>index.php/ejemplo/usuario/datos',
            {},
            function(){},
            function(datos){
              //$("#tablaDatos").remove();
                var strtabla = "<thead><tr><td colspan='2'>Lugar</td>";
                var strDiv = "</tr><tr><td>Usuario</td><td>Rol</td>";
                var cont=0;

                $(datos).each(function(i,e){



                    strtabla += "<td colspan='2'id='c-"+e.id+"' data-lugar='"+(e.id)+"'>"+e.nombre+"</td>";
                    cont++;

                    strDiv += "<td  id='c-"+e.id+"' data-lugar='"+(e.id)+"'>Nº A.</td><td  id='c-"+e.id+"' data-lugar='"+(e.id)+"'>Saldo</td>";


                });

                strtabla += strDiv+"</tr></thead>";
                $("#tablaDatos").append(strtabla);
                cargaNum(cont, datoFechaI, datoFechaF); // esta funcion es para crear el body de la tabla con otros datos al igual que el thead se crea con la funcion append dependiendo los datos.
        });
      }
```

a lo cual me borra la tabla pero no crea la nueva...
alguien que me pueda ayudar ¿?

Comment: es posible que al refrescar la tabla, los nuevos datos se estén agregando dentro de `#tablaDatos`, por lo tanto si lo borrar ya no se cargan. La solución podría ser borrar algún elemento interno, no el `#tablaDatos`. Para resolver tu duda parece importante conocer la estructura de tu *html*, así como la implementación del método `tablaP`

Comment: @spuente,agregué como creo el thead de mi tabla, no puse el body por que es mas pero se crea de la misma manera con la función append y dependiendo los datos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba cambiar el `$("#tablaDatos").remove();`
por `$("#tablaDatos").html("");`
lo que pasa es que el `$("#tablaDatos").remove();` elimina la tabla por completo y cuando tratas de agregar la nueva ese elemento ya no existe por eso no lo crea con `$("#tablaDatos").html("");` lo que se hace es cambiar el contenido **html** interno del elemento **table** por **""** lo que lo deja vacio y listo para el nuevo contenido.Espero te ayude.

tambien puedes usar `$("#tablaDatos").empty();` logrando el mismo resultado.

Comment: $("#tablaDatos").empty() elimina todo el contenido del elemento

Comment: si es verdad tienes razon gracias!!

Comment: Gracias @user2755565 ya había encontrado la solución que de echo es la misma que tu me estas dando jajaa, aun así muchas gracias.